# Password hashing changing in CakePHP/Croogo redeploy

Tags: cakephp, heroku, github, cakephp-2.0, croogo

I am trying to deploy a Croogo/Cakephp installation to Heroku using Heroku's Cedar stack.

Everytime we redeploy to Heroku, however, we are unable to reauthenticate users created with the previous deployment and have to recreate the database from scratch.  We suspect that it is an issue with the password hashing.  The security salt is remaining the same across deployments however.  Is there anything else that might change that would cause hashing to fail?

Comment: I have the same problem on Heroku. My problem is when I try to save the user after requesting a new password. The user is not saved. This is the only part that does not work, though. Have you found a solution to your problem?